# While syncing or executing PAF scripts to ALM if an error occurs with the following keywords <link> or </hr> .How to resolve this issue?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While syncing or executing PAF scripts to ALM if an error occurs with the following keywords `**<link>**` or `**</hr>**` .How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether we have special characters in the activity files and flow files.